# SQL Query Assistance (ObjectPropertyvalue)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I need help with the following query.

```
select * 
from xr.ObjectPropertyvalue 
where objectid in (
    select objectid 
    from xr.objectpropertyvalue 
    where endversion in 
             (select max(endversion) 
              from xr.ObjectPropertyValue 
              group by objectid having count(endversion) > 1
   )
 )
```

What I was trying to do is to look for an entry on the table that has the highest end version and the objectid being unique.

```
Ex.
    Object id 1's highest version = 3
    Object id 2 highest version =4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show some simple data and expect output. Also, are you using mysql or sql-server?

Comment: @EricZ table consist of multiple entries for the same object ID but different end versions would just like to get results for highest version for each distinct objectid. And I'm using sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you may try this query (un-tested, I don't have sql-server environment now)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY endversion DESC)  
  FROM xr.ObjectPropertyvalue
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE c.rn = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.objectid = c.objectid AND c2.rn = 2)
ORDER BY c.objectid
```